tkinter: Отрисовка расходящихся лучей
Задание: нарисовать расходящиеся по кругу лучи в виде секторов разного цвета. Что-то вот не ладится: и бесконечно и не в ту сторону лучи рисует
from random import *
from math import *
from tkinter import *
size = 600
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=size, height=size)
canvas.pack()
diapason = 0
ygol=0
R=1
x=1
y=1
for i in range(0, 360000, 35):
    colors = choice(['blue','green','red'])
    phi = i*pi
    x0 = 300
    y0 = 300
    x = 600*cos(phi*i*100)
    y = 600*sin(phi*i*100)
    R = (x**2 + y**2)**0.5
    canvas.create_line(x0, y0, R+i+100, R+100, fill=colors, width=35) #нижняя
    canvas.create_line(x0, y0, R-i+100, R+100, fill=colors, width=35) #часть
    canvas.create_line(x0, y0, R+100, R-i+100, fill=colors, width=35) #первая четверть
    canvas.create_line(x0, y0, R-100, R-i-100, fill=colors, width=35)
    root.update()


А как это должно выглядеть?

@MBo у меня есть только словесное описание сиего творения: расходящиеся по кругу лучи в виде секторов разного цвета  :(

для универского задания слишком хило как-то.

@strawdog так хило, что аж никто не помог?

@Наталия возможно, никто не захотел тратить свое время на такое.

@strawdog если всё так просто как вы говорите, то помощь не заняла бы много времени

Вероятно, с create_arc будет проще.

@MBo спасибо, попробую
